# filtering results using isotope works with control F5 only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to filter a grid view in JavaScript with jQuery Isotope, it works fine if I click control F5, or I have my developer tools open, but when I just go to the url in a normal way, or refresh the page, it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
 $(window).load(function(){     
        var dataFilters = [];
        dataFilters = getdataFilters();
        //dataFilters now has the value of = [".val1",".val2"]
        $('#grid').isotope({ filter: dataFilters.join(', ') });
    });
```

The reason I am using window.load is that I am waiting for all images to be loaded, then I filter them.

Answer (score 0):

It's precisely because you're using `window.load` that you are only able to filter when refreshing the page, since the filter functionality is only declared there.

If you want to initialize isotope only when all of your images have loaded, you can use the imagesloaded library (by the same developer) in conjunction with isotope.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded

Sample code from the documentation:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init Isotope after all images have loaded
  $grid.isotope({
    // options...
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it gave me this error : `TypeError: $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function(…)`

Comment: You'll need to add a script src to your page for the imagesloaded library to be used

Comment: But I tried this on my development environment with window.load, it's working fine, I can refresh the page or navigate to the page, and it's working fine, when I deployed my code to the production, it's not working there. I am viewing both on chrome